# The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided | Aws::Sigv4::Signer | Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-selling-partner-api

I'm getting this error

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided
> The Canonical String for this request should have been
> The String-to-Sign should have been

I am trying to implement the SP APIs in rails.
I've fetched the access-token from https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token endpoint.
And after wards created the temporary session token using Aws::STS::Client.
I used Aws::Sigv4::Signer for signature.

**First Step (Access Token)**

```
payload = {
  grant_type: 'refresh_token',
  client_id: [ClientId],
  refresh_token: [RefreshToken],
  client_secret: [ClientSecret],
}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = HTTParty.post("https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token", body: payload.to_json, headers: headers)
access_token = response["access_token"]
```

**Second Step (Create Assume Role Using AWS::STS)**

```
    result = sts = Aws::STS::Client.new(
      region: "us-east-1",
      credentials: Aws::Credentials.new("aws-access-key", "aws-secret-key")
    ).assume_role({
      role_arn: "role_arn",
      role_session_name: 'sp-api'
    })
```

```
enter code here
```

**Third Step (Create Signature )**

```
    signer = Aws::Sigv4::Signer.new(
      service: 'execute-api',
      region: 'us-east-1',
      # static credentials
      access_key_id: access_key_id,
      secret_access_key: secret_access_key,
      session_token: session_token
    )
    
    signature = signer.sign_request(
      http_method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/orders/v0/orders/ordersID',
      headers: {
        'host' => 'sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com',
        'X-Amz-Access-Token' => access_token,
      })
```

**Final Step (To call the API with the Signature Headers)**

```
    headers = {
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
      "host" => signature.headers["host"],
      "X-Amz-Date" => signature.headers['x-amz-date'],
      "X-Amz-Security-Token" => signature.headers["x-amz-security-token"],
      "X-Amz-Content-Sha256" => signature.headers["x-amz-content-sha256"],
      "Authorization" => signature.headers['authorization']
    }
    
    data = HTTParty.send(:get, "https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/orders/v0/orders/ordersID", headers: headers)
```

Comment: Same issue. Any luck resolving this?